# System wide noise on high power BLDC controller prototype

Tags: mosfet, noise, brushless-dc-motor, hall-effect

I'm designing a highish power BLDC motor diver (120A continuous 48V nominal 90V max) BLDC controller and am having noise issues caused by the mosfet switching.

Basically at the high and low transitions of the phases every signal in the system experiences a noise spike. The symptom of this problem is that at a high enough voltage (>30V) the interrupt that controls speed calculations is being triggered leading to falsely high RPM readings and thus the control slowing the motor to a stop. However as part of a larger system this noise could very easily cause far larger problems if it moves through ground as I expected it is.

I have increased the gate resistors and added a shotkey and smaller resistor in parallel, which reduces and removes the noise by slowing down the rise and fall times when the motor is not connected, however, when driving the motor it is almost like the gate resistors are ignored on two of the three phases, I added a PNP transistor to hopefully help as a miller clamp, but I'm partially convinced that seeing as the gate resistor is so high, the transistor is already inactive by the time that the effect is happening...

Additional information:
With motor, 30V 0.3A 30ish RPM
[image: with motor attached and running][image: attached][image: attached]

no load attached
[image: no load single transition]
[image: no load 1 cycle]
[image: no load zoomed out]

More voltage, more noise
Problem is worse when motor is driven counter clockwise...

power for the microcontroller and halls is coming from a USB port at the moment and ground is tied through a ferrite bead, I don't think it is EMF as shielding the hall wires has no notable effect and the noise is present in all signals.
Microcontroller is RP2040
snubber diodes are present, rc snubber has no noticeable effect
Driver Chip dead time is 200ns
Control scheme is hall driven Space vector modulation

This current board does not use a full ground plane as I was worried about ground loops, however the issues was the same in a previous board with a full ground plane.

Phase outputs and power inputs are machined aluminium blocks with 3 MOSFETs in parallel and large eyelets

VCC to gnd decoupling is about 2000uF electolytics plus a few 1uF ceramics

Gate resistors sit at 160 Ohm CHG 20 Ohm Discharge, I did have potentiometers on there at one point and went up to 500 ohms, but seeing as the motor can somehow ignore the gate resistors it doesn't really make much difference

The lines from the driver Chip to the gates are kinda long, but is sadly unavoidable given the huge aluminium blocks

I'm fairly confident that I could code or opto-couple my way out of this, but as part of a wider system I think people might get annoyed with 2V drops and spikes at 5kHz intervals.